# Why is Component not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am creating a postcard application.
To utilize the webcam I am using **webkitURL** which is available on the window object and building the app using **react**

I tried to test each function separately and all was well, but once I placed everything together I get this error  `'Component' is not defined'` in the console.

Here is a screenshot

[Given Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6nys.png)

So ***my question is:**

why is Component not available?

Is it okay to save my Photo and Camera functions after my Capture component?

Here is my current code as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


// CSS Styling

const styles = {
  capture: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  picSize: {
    display: 'flex',
    maxWidth: 340,
    maxHeight: 340,
    minWidth: 340,
    minHeight: 340,
    margin: 30,
  },
  box: {
    maxWidth: 340,
    maxHeight: 340,
    minWidth: 340,
    minHeight: 340,
    border: '10px solid green',
  }
}

//Components

class Capture extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
  constraints: { audio: false, video: { width: 400, height: 300 } }
  };
    this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this);  
    this.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this);  
    this.clearPhoto = this.clearPhoto.bind(this);  
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const constraints = this.state.constraints;  
    const getUserMedia = (params) => (  
  new Promise((successCallback, errorCallback) => {
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.call(navigator, params, successCallback, errorCallback);
  })
);

getUserMedia(constraints)  
.then((stream) => {
  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  const vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

this.clearPhoto(); 
  }
clearPhoto(){
      const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');  
      const photo = document.getElementById('photo');  
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
      const { width, height } = this.state.constraints.video;  
      context.fillStyle = '#FFF';  
      context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

      const data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');  
      photo.setAttribute('src', data); 
    }
handleStartClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    this.takePicture();  
    }
takePicture(){
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');  
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    const video = document.querySelector('video');  
    const photo = document.getElementById('photo');  
    const { width, height } = this.state.constraints.video;

    canvas.width = width;  
    canvas.height = height;  
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    const data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');  
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);  
}
render() {
    return (  
      <div className="capture"
        style={ styles.capture }
      >
        <Camera
          handleStartClick={ this.handleStartClick }
        />
        <canvas id="canvas"
          style={ styles.picSize }
          hidden
        ></canvas>
        <Photo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const Camera = (props) => (
  <div className="camera"
    style={ styles.box }
  >
    <video id="video"
      style={ styles.picSize }
    ></video>
    <a id="startButton"
      onClick={ props.handleStartClick }
      style={ styles.button }
    >Take photo</a>
  </div>
);

const Photo = (props) => (
    <div className="output"
    style={ styles.box }
  >
    <img id="photo" alt="Your photo"
      style={ styles.picSize }
    />
    <a id="saveButton"
      onClick={ props.handleSaveClick }
      style={ styles.button }
    >Save Photo</a>
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Capture />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Aren't it should be `extends React.Component`?

Comment: @masterpreenz Thanks! wow I can't believe I forgot that, thats fixed and now its stating that styles is not defined

Answer (score 14):

You haven't declared `Component` and using it to extend your class `Capture`.

First you need import it like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

Or as @masterpreenz suggested in the comment change your class declaration to:

```
class Capture extends React.Component {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It should be `import React, { Component } from 'react'`. You still need the React part.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

into

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

`styles` is not defined because you never created the styles object. From your code you're trying to access some properties of the `styles` object which are currently not defined.
You need to create the `styles` object and define those properties for them to be available.

Comment: Copy, great catch. I updated my code. I highly appreciate that